# Generic Generics in Managed C++

Tags: .net, generics, .net-2.0, managed-c++

I want to create a **List** of **KeyValuePair**s in a managed C++ project. Here is the syntax I'm using

```
List<KeyValuePair<String^, String^>^>^ thing;
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair ^', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

I basically want to do this (C#)

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> thing;
```

but in managed C++. Oh and in .Net 2.0. Any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> KeyValuePair does not itself need to be a handle. Duh.

Because it's a value type, not a reference type (i.e. `struct` instead of `class` in C#).

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out:

```
List<KeyValuePair<String^, String^>>^ thing;
```

KeyValuePair does not itself need to be a handle. Duh.