# Creating a KeyValuePair in Managed C++

Tags: .net, generics, visual-c++, .net-2.0, managed-c++

I have yet another managed C++ KeyValuePair question where I know what to do in C#, but am having a hard time translating to managed C++. Here is the code that does what I want to do in C#:

```
KeyValuePair<String, String> KVP = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("this", "that");
```

I've reflected it into MC++ and get this:

```
KeyValuePair<String __gc*, String __gc*> __gc* KVP = (S"this", S"that");
```

which I'm translating to:

```
KeyValuePair<String ^, String ^> KVP = (gcnew String("this"), gcnew String("that"));
```

I know from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341477/generic-generics-in-managed-c) that KeyValuePair is a value type; is the problem that it's a value type in C++ and a reference type in C#? Can anyone tell me how to set the key and value of a KeyValuePair from C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

`KeyValuePair< String ^, String ^> k(gcnew String("Foo"), gcnew String("Bar"));`

KeyValuePair is an immutable type, so you have to pass everything to the constructor, which looks the same as in C#, except you write it like this if the object is on the stack.

Comment: KeyValuPair is not an immutable type.

Comment: This also worked, but I couldn't accept both so I voted you both up.

Comment: Actually, it is immutable. Here's a post by the designer explaining why https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90998

Comment: Switched to this as best answer because of the immutable citation

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair< System::String^, System::String^>^ k = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair< System::String^, System::String^>(gcnew System::String("foo") ,gcnew System::String("bar"))   ;
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm confused as to why. Is KeyValuePair a value type?